Bitensors at three or more space-time points
Bitensors, i.e. tensors at two points that have indices belonging to either of them, have been used in the literature quite a bit and there are many calculations involving them. They are the go-to formalism when treating QFT propagators and their derivatives in a curved space-time background. We write a bitensor as $T^{\mu\nu\ldots\alpha'\beta'\ldots}(x,y)$, where unprimed indices belong to $x$ and primed indices to $y$. However, I have only ever seen them treated with two space-time points.
All bitensors in maximally symmetric spaces can be written as functions of the geodesic distance $\ell(x,y)$ of the two points $x$ and $y$ times some basis tensors. These basis tensors are the metric at either point $g_{\mu\nu}(x)$ and $g_{\mu'\nu'}(y)$, the parallel transport tensor $g_{\mu\nu'}(x,y)$ that moves indices from $x$ to $y$ and the vector $n_\mu(x,y) = \nabla_\mu\ell(x,y)$. With this, we have some nice statements like $g_{\mu\nu'}(x,y)n^{\nu'}(x,y) = -n_\mu(x,y)$. But what happens when we add another point $z$ with double-primed indices into the mix? Now, we have three sets of bitensors, one for each of the point combinations $(x,y)$, $(x,z)$ and $(y,z)$. Are there any nice statements about contractions of these objects? For example, I am interested in $n^{\mu'}(x,y)n_{\mu'}(y,z)=???$. Is there a way to express this nicely in terms of the basis objects for $(x,z)$? The problem I see with this is that it should depend on all three of $x,y,z$. But maybe the $y$ dependence can be factored out into a scalar coefficient?
I need this for calculations that involve multiple propagators, for example a loop integral in curved background for a gluon with a 4-contact interaction. Ignoring all physical technicalities like gauge etc., we have a contribution for the two-point function $\langle A_\mu(x) A_{\nu''}(z) \rangle$ that is a coincident loop at $y$ and then we have two propagators like $\mathcal{M} = G_{\mu\rho'}(x,y) (\mathrm{loop})^{\rho'\sigma'}(y) G_{\sigma'\nu''}(y,z)$. If I expand the propagators in bitensors, the aforementioned contractions show up.
